# TypeError: map[$_get] is not a function , Dart

Tags: dart, factory, fromjson, jsondecodeerror

I am writing a program that uses HTTP to get a list of themes from a server, and when transforming the data from JSON I am getting this error.

```
TypeError: map[$_get] is not a function
packages/outlook/src/provider/response.dart 28:19                    fromHTTP
packages/outlook/src/provider/outlook.impl.dart 74:7                 <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1653:54                                 runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                           handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                           handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                           _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 566:5                            [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 639:7                            callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                     _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                      _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15  <fn>
```

here is the method of getting the themes:

```dart
 Future<OtlResponse<List<OutlookTheme>>> getThemes() {
    return http
        .post(serverDomain,
        body: jsonEncode({'method': RequestMethods.getThemes.name,}))
        .then((http.Response resp) {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(resp.body);
     
      OtlResponse<List<OutlookTheme>> response =
      OtlResponse<List<OutlookTheme>>.fromHTTP(
          map: body,
          data: List.from(body['themes'])
              .map(( themeMap) => OutlookTheme.fromMap(Map.from(themeMap)))
              .toList());

      return response;
    });
  }
```

After decoding the response I am transforming it into and OtlResponse using this factory as shown here:

```dart
  factory OtlResponse.fromHTTP({required Map<String, dynamic> map, required T data}) {
    return OtlResponse<T>(
      success: map['success'] as bool,
      data: data,
      context: map['context'] as String,
      statusCode: map['statusCode'] as int,
      methodId: (map['method'] as String).toEnum(RequestMethods.values),
    );
  }
```

According to the log , the error is coming from the fromHTTP() factory and where am calling it in the getThemes method. I tried using Map.from() after decoding and its not working. What can I do to fix this? any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well after stopping main run process and running it, it's now working.